# gwtp Accessing uibinder input, div, span using DOM

Tags: dom, gwt, uibinder, gwtp

I wanted to access the elements in uibinders using DOM or document interface in presenters, is it possible.

wanted to get the element and attach handler to it.

I have input, select, div, span element in uibinders. Is it possible to achieve.

I tried to get using DOM and Document it returns null.

```
    <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.content1}" ui:field="containerPanel1">
        <div class="{style.rightAlign}" id="container">
            <g:FormPanel styleName="{style.formLayout}" ui:field="formPanel1">
                <g:HTMLPanel width="100%" height="100%">
                    <div id="inner" class="{style.horiCon}">
                        <div class="{style.label}">
                            <ui:msg key="name" description="Name of the user">Name</ui:msg>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="name"
                            placeholder="FirstName" class="{style.textboxFirstName}" />
                        <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="LastName"
                            name="name" class="{style.textboxLastName}" />
                        <span id="nameError" class="{style.errorMsgHide}">Error</span>
                    </div>
                </g:HTMLPanel>
            </g:FormPanel>
        </div>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
```

Presenter

```
@Override
protected void onBind() {
    super.onBind();
        Window.alert("" + DOM.getElementById("firstName"));
                // returns null;
}

@Override
protected void onReveal() {
    super.onReveal();
    Window.alert("" + DOM.getElementById("firstName"));
                // returns <input class="GG1RCY0BHB" id="firstName" name="name" placeholder="FirstName" type="text">
}
```

Onbind() returns null and onreveal() returns

after that when I do

```
TextBox.wrap(DOM.getElementById("firstName"));
```

I am getting

```
java.lang.AssertionError: A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel.detachOnWindowClose(RootPanel.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox.wrap(TextBox.java:69)
```

What is the issue? Can I use Rootpanel in presenter to get the reference?
Please help me.

Thanks In Advance,
Jose.

Comment: Please post the exact code you tried and what lines produced problems.

Answer (score 0):

To access `DOM` elements the elements need to get attached to the `DOM` first, otherwise it will return `null`. You can use the `DOM.getElementByID("id")` in overridden `onLoad()` method in your `ui-binder` java class .

```
@Override
void onLoad()
{
    DOM.getElementByID("id");
}
```

You Mentioned the **input, select, div, span element in uibinders.** Why not use a `ui:field` and access the field directly to add handlers etc? Just a thought.
select is `GWT` `ListBox` there is `FlowPanel` is a div likewise.

Comment: I am using gwtp and I have above content in uibinder, Onload() of which class do I need to use to get DOM.getElementById() work. that belongs to Widget.

Comment: There is one java file with the name of uibinder file. But it doesn't have onload method.                                                              public class TestInsertView extends ViewImpl implements
  TestInsertPresenter.MyView {} it doesn't have onload method.

Comment: you are talking about the composite implementation, But I have a ViewImpl implementation class, how can I get access to DOM element in this class.